# Accessing Google Spreadsheet with Zend without Authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets

I am attempting to access a public spreadsheet that does not require authentication to access. I am following the guidance found on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html) to access the spreadsheet, however, the docs specify how to do it using an authenticated user. There does not seem to be any guidance on accessing public spreadsheets without authentication.

So, does anyone have any suggestions how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with google spreadsheets you can just leave the authentication blank if it's a public sheet; you only start to get errors when it's a private sheet.