# Google Docs API without Authentication

Tags: google-docs-api

Is it possible to query publicly shared user documents in Google Docs without authentication?

The specific end goal I am looking for is to be able to supply a user id, and then list all publicly shared docs with a particular tagged in a collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the Google Docs API, you will need to be authorized to be able to list these publicly shared files.

Comment: not the answer I was hoping to hear, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: If a specific document is wanted you can access it using the URL, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answer is 100% correct. If the document is shared globally (publicly accessible), then it should be possible according to these Stack Overflow posts:

[Accessing Google Spreadsheet with Zend without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807684/accessing-google-spreadsheet-with-zend-without-authentication)

or

[Read content of public shared file in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664332/read-content-of-public-shared-file-in-google-drive)