# Read content of public shared file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a Google Drive application.

The application needs to read the contents of a publically shared file in someone's Google Drive.

How can I do this?

Is there an API to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the Google Drive API, after setting the ACL of the file to be public you can directly access the file using the `webContentLink` attribute of the file metadata which should not require any authentication/authorization when the file is public.

This is a feil metadata example: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

This is how to get the file metadata using common client libraries: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Thanks. So can i use simple 'curl' tool to fetch the contents from `webContentLink`? Will the link permanent or limited for a period of time?

Comment: Yes, if the file is shared publicly. It will follow a redirect and then download the file.

Comment: I have tried much but failed to make get request without OAuth. :/

Comment: @NicolasGarnier I have been unable to make progress with this. Could you possibly post a simple code example?

Answer (score 4):

While webContentLink does provide link to download or view the content in a browser, it appears to me that it still requires authentication or that the user is already logged in to view the file, even if it is shared as "public"

I hope the plan is to make this work as described above, that public files can be viewed without any authentication whatsoever.