# How to read/write publicly shared file which is in others google drive account using share link from my application, Android?

Tags: android, share, google-drive-android-api

I want to read/write publicly shared file which is in others google drive account using share link. How can I do that?. I am able to access file from my account successfully but how can i access others people google drive file which is publicly shared. I already have gone this link [Read content of public shared file in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664332/read-content-of-public-shared-file-in-google-drive) but didn't get much info about how to implement this. Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding your question (receiving a link - in an e-mail... - to a shared file), a properly shared file to which you have write permission should be available in the Google drive app. I it regularly it for just that. And yes, it works for writing as well as reading.

Comment: Ya file have all permission read as well as write too. My question how to implement this. Mean how can i access file from my app programmatically which is in others google drive account using share link.