# Read contents in a public shared google drive in android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I was searching for a method to view the contents of a public shared google drive folder. I tried Drive Api but unfortunately it doesn't seems to work with this matter. I have read in some threads that the google rest api can do it without any authorization. But I couldn't find any sample code for that. I have the folder ID and I can access/download it via browser.

also found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664332/read-content-of-public-shared-file-in-google-drive)

Comment: Were you able to obtain the webContentLink ?

Comment: @noogui I have the link for public folder. how do I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching and testing, I was able to achieve what I was thirsting for. If anyone who had the same problem comes here, I will leave here what I did.

You have to import the json file that has credentials.

**Global variables**

```
private static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;
private final HttpTransport m_transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
private final JsonFactory m_jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private GoogleAccountCredential m_credential;
private static Drive m_client;
```

inside **onCreate**

```
m_client = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
            m_transport, m_jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("YourAppName")
            .build();
```

You will be able to acquire the json file when you create a **OAuth Client ID** . However if you just lost the json file by accident, you just have to create a new **Service Account Key** under the same project and that **json** file will be get accepted.

After this you will be able to use **REST** api and can access **public shared folders** and download/read the contents inside it.